# Excel Conditional Formatting of Rows based on multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet with columns A-K and rows 1-56. If any value in D3 through J3 goes below 0, I want the entire row (A through K ) to have a special format. I've gotten close in Excel 2010 by using the *Home ->Conditional Formatting->Manage Rules->New Rule* and I created a formula rule where the Formula is

```
=($D3:$J3)<0
```

and in the *Applies to* I have
    =$A$3:$K:$56

What happens now is it works great for any value in Column D **ONLY**. When values in E-J change I get no formatting. Anybody know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this formula instead: `=COUNTIF($D3:$J3,"<0")>0`